# error in __connection_block_invoke_2: Connection interrupted only received on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

When I'm testing my app on an iPad I repeatedly receive this error: "error in __connection_block_invoke_2: Connection interrupted".

I have read a lot of posts that suggest it's something to do with memory leaks and overloading my RAM, however it has pretty low usage across the board.

Can anyone tell me what it actually means and what is usually the culprit for this error?

As I have mentioned the other posts (referring to memory leaks and overloading RAM) actually tells us what the "Received memory warning." error is caused by, this is not a duplicate of that post.

Comment: I don't know why this is marked as duplicate. There are few question around here asking the same thing. I noticed that I don't receive this error when I try in the simulator. Only when connected to the device.

Comment: I did update the question pointing this out on the bottom line, rmaddy doesn't seem to care. One of the things I hate about this website is that once you knock together enough correct answers you have absolute power.

Comment: I just noticed that the error message isn't here anymore. I'm using CocoaPods and updated this morning, but I'm not sure it's related. I'll try to find where it comes from.

Comment: This is not a duplicate! How do you unmark as duplicate? I'm going to post another because this is a problem still.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't unmark it as a duplicate, only rmaddy (the user who marked it) can do that.

Comment: I'm getting this error too. In searching for an answer I've found this forum post, which indicates that you should maybe just consider it to be a warning that you can ignore. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/28367